# Groovy code,using java jar complains unable to resolve class

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij, I added the java class jar as dependency in project settings > module > dependency.
Still while executing it complains:
Groovyc: unable to resolve class com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

I went through different questions here regarding same issue, and did all that was recommended, still the error persists.

Comment: There is not enough information, to answer yet. Is class from jar highlighted and accessible to auto-completion tools, while you editing your groovy script? There is a string in __run__ window, describing run configuration command. It contains __-classpath__ key followed with semicolon separated classpath entryes. Is your jar listed there?

Comment: The class from the jar is accessible by the IDE auto completion.

Comment: I am unable to find -classpath key in the run configurations. Can you tell where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be known issue on windows with spaces in path [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Class+Loading). Move your files to a path without spaces.

-classpath is displayed in run window. First line in that output window shows you java call with all arguments. Check existance of jar file there, if first link isn't your case.